# Cout does not print text from a file without endl

Tags: linux, file, c++11, cout

I created a program to pass the values ​​from the file to the string "op", using the getline function and then print the values ​​to the screen.

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string op;
   while(getline(cin, op))
   {
      cout << op;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

`

But, cout does not print all values. The cout only prints all values ​​if there is an "endl".

FILE:
`

```
1+2
2+3\5
```

`
INPUT WITHOUT endl:

`2+3\5`

INPUT WITH endl:

```
1+2
2+3\5
```

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: `cout.flush(),` is correct.  Please edit your post to show the code that did not work.

Comment: Bet your file has Windows style CRLF line endings.